# whats wrong with this statement(count from 0-9)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get this code to calculate 5 and print numbers by 5's with a while statement of 7, so I want it to loop through, generating a different number 7 times; however, when it gets to a number over 10, I want it to start back over at 0 and ignore the 10.

This is my code:

```
while z < 7:
firstpickplusfive = int(firstpickplusfive) + 1
counts = counts + 1
if counts == 1:
if firstpickplusfive > 9:
firstpickplusfive = 0
if counts == 5:
print firstpickplusfive
z = int(z) + 1
```

The code prints the first number, but freezes on printing any others.  Why isn't this working?

Comment: You should correct your codes indentation

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  In a language where indentation is crucial, it is also crucial that you provide us the same indentation that you are testing with.

Comment: please indent the code exactly like you have it in the source code... python is sensitive and if I make a inference about your post then the code is not even compiling here...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not in the loop. Python's code blocks are created with indents:

```
while z < 7:
    firstpickplusfive = int(firstpickplusfive) + 1
    counts = counts + 1
    if counts == 1:
        if firstpickplusfive > 9:
          firstpickplusfive = 0
    if counts == 5:
        print firstpickplusfive
    z = int(z) + 1
```

Comment: That's probably just a copy-paste error.  He indented nothing.  Your "solution" still includes indentation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you were trying to achieve:

```
import random

x = random.randint(1,9)
for i in range(1,8):
    print x
    x += 5
    if x >= 10:
        x -= 9
```

This generates a random number, and adds 5 until it passes 10, then subtracts 9, and it does this seven times. If I understand your question correctly, this is what you were trying to do. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

no this is not what I was trying to do here is what I am trying to do.

```
counts = 0
r = 0
firstpickplusfive = 7
p = firstpickplusfive + 5
while r < 3:
    firstpickplusfive = p + counts
    if firstpickplusfive > 6:
        firstpickplusfive = firstpickplusfive + counts - 10 
    if p > 9:
        p = firstpickplusfive + counts  

    print firstpickplusfive
    counts = counts + 1

    r = int(r) + 1
```

it works alone, but when I add it to the script I am trying to write it doesn't work...if there is a simpler way to do it I would appreciate knowing it.

ie.
number = number + 5 + 0
then 
number = number + 5 + 1.....ect which

example 7 + 5 + 0 = 12, 
        7 + 5 + 1 = 13.........

if the number is equal to 10 then I want it to drop the tens place and keep the 1's place

example 7 + 5 + 0 = 2, 
        7 + 5 + 1 = 3

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier method:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    num = 7
    num += 5
    num +=(i-1)
    if num >=10:
        num -= 10

    print num
    i+=1
```

Try this in your script, does it work?

Comment: no doesn't work brings back traceback.....think I have figured out or at least what I have is workable...thanks all for the help

Comment: What's the traceback?

Comment: I cant remember the trace back but I know it didn't work I will put on paste the whole code and you can look at it and make changes if you want, right now I am having issues with putting stuff in my dbase perhaps you can look at that also. http://pastebin.com/EzUBLyLS

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help you any further, this is about the limits of my knowledge, I am a relative novice.

Comment: well thanks for your help anyway mr. yang I appreciate it